# PyQt & Python2.3

Tags: python, pyqt, python-2.3

Is there a PyQt3 (Or 4) Windows binary installer for Python 2.3? I've googled around for an hour now but to no avail. Why am I using version 2.3? With my project file size is paramount. Without the interface, un-needed modules and compressing using UPX the resulting .exe size is a mear 750KB's. Just need to add the interface which will beaf the size up considerably I know but it will still be a good size.

So anyone know how I can install PyQt3 or 4 with Python2.3?

Comment: There is v3.8 but it only supports Qt2, think about all the pain, awww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always compile from [source](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-win-gpl-4.8.2.zip), but there's probably good reason they don't release a binary for 2.3 and it's probably unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.3 is extremely old. You really shouldn't be using it at all. I seriously doubt there's any qt bindings for it that would even compile. Why do you think using python 2.3 will save you so much file size?

Adding pyqt will probably increase your file size by 10s of megabytes at least. Just use python at least 2.6. This is definitely a case of premature optimization. And optimizing something stupid like file size.

Comment: From today's viewpoint, Python 2.3 sucks. It lacks 7 years of really cool improvements. It merely has generators, but not even genrator expressions, decorators, with statements, a ton of neat libraries, and much much more.

Comment: Yes, running python 2.3 because the executable is smaller is like running windows 95 because it takes up less space.

Comment: 'optimizing something stupid like file size' - if you read his question: "project file size is paramount".

Comment: @Corey: Yes, but that is incompatible with a gui, especially pyQt